# Passing vue slot generated inputs to root vue instance

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js

Is it possible to pass a slot generated input fields value to the root vue instance?

Here is my blade code:

```
<template slot="update">          
    <td>
        <div>
            <input :value="name" type="text"/>
        </div>
    </td>
</template>
```

I want to pass the user input of the `textbox` on my root vue instance?

Is is possible and how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Two things that can help you:

1. You may access the root instance from any child by [using `this.$root`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-root).
2. You can communicate between components by using [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Instance-Methods-Events), specifically the `$emit` and `$on` methods.

By using these two, you can easily pass changes that happen to an input in some child component to the root instance. Check out [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/2176/).

Comment: Got it! Thanks @mzgajner :)